# Get Source file,method and line in exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am trying to get details from an exception occurred in my c# (4.0) asp.net web application. I have .pdb file in bin folder. The following code is not working as expected -

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //throwing Exception
        using (SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Get a StackTrace object for the exception
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exception, true);

        //Get the first stack frame
        StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0); //returns {PermissionDemand at offset 5316022 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0}

        //Get the file name
        string fileName = frame.GetFileName(); //returns null

        //Get the method name
        string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name; //returns PermissionDemand

        //Get the line number from the stack frame
        int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber(); //returns 0

        //Get the column number
        int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber(); //returns 0              
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

update:
       "StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1); " solved this issue.

Comment: Does exception.StackTrace help? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx)

Comment: That is returning you the entire error string. I don't want that.

Comment: Your post starts with "I am trying to get details from an exception". The StackTrace property returns a string representation of the stack trace. It does not return the entire error string. This would be generated by exception.ToString(). Please be more specific

Comment: My subject is "Get Source file,method and line in c# asp.net exception" and what i want to do is in try ... catch block. Read the code carefully.

Comment: From your update, it seems you found the answer to your own question. Please post an answer and accept it. It will greatly improve readability for people encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//Remove this line
StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

//Add this line
StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1);
```